# Using ifnum with setlength

Tags: macros

i need to understand this line of code with details:

```
\ifnum\thetype@box=0\setlength{\spacebottom}{\expandafter\csname
spacebottom#1\endcsname}\fi
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `\ifnum` and `\setlength` are not related here. `\ifnum` tests integers, in this case it checks if the value of `\thetype@box` is zero. If so, `\setlength` sets `\spacebottom` to whatever the value of the user supplied macro `spacebottom#1` is. I;m not entirely sure this is a good way of doing this.

Comment: Also, `\expandafter` in this context does not accomplish anything, best I can tell.

Comment: Indeed, `\expandafter` tries to expand the `s` of `spacebottom`, which is normally an unexpandable character token. Besides, everything between `\csname` and `\endcsname` is recursively expanded, by definition of `\csname`...

Comment: In addition to the `\expandafter` doing nothing useful there should be a space after the `0` but also you have just copied a line out of context so it is not easy to say what it does, the `#1` means it is part of a definition but you have not shown the rest of the definition, not the use of the command being defined..

Comment: Finally, \fi ends the code executed by \ifnum.

Answer (score 4):

On my system `\setlength` is defined as follows:

```
\setlength=macro:
#1#2->#1 #2\relax
```

The snippet of code provided by you contains `#1`. Seems this is part of something that at some stage of processing might go into the definition-text of a macro.

Assuming that `@` is of category code 11(letter) (→`\makeatletter`..`\makeatother`), the sequence

```
\ifnum\thetype@box=0\setlength{\spacebottom}{\expandafter\csname
spacebottom#1\endcsname}\fi
```

yields:

`\ifnum` triggers gathering the first TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity and obtaining its value from `\thetype@box`.
After that `\ifnum` triggers gathering the relation-sign from `=`.
After that `\ifnum` triggers gathering tokens that belong to the second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

Thus a stage like this is reached:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% Value of \ifnum's first TeX-<number>-quantity and relation-sign "=" gathered/obtained.
% Process of gathering tokens that belong to \ifnum's second TeX-<number>-quantity (and afterwards 
% obtaining that quantity's value) started and in progress:
0\setlength{\spacebottom}{\expandafter\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname}\fi
```

The digit-character-token `0` is found. Thus the process of gathering tokens that belong to `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity forms a process of gathering more digit-character-tokens or something that terminates the process of gathering, hereby expanding expandable tokens:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% Value of  \ifnum's first TeX-<number>-quantity and relation-sign "=" gathered/obtained. 
% Digit-character-token "0" of \ifnum's second  TeX-<number>-quantity found, thus the process of
% gathering tokens that belong to \ifnum's second TeX-<number>-quantity is still in progress and now
% forms a process of gathering more digit-character-tokens or something that terminates the
% process of gathering, hereby expanding expandable tokens:
\setlength{\spacebottom}{\expandafter\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname}\fi
```

Now, while the process of gathering tokens that belong to `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity is still in progress,  the macro `\setlength` gets expanded*—I think this should take place when the  process of gathering tokens that belong to `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity is terminated*:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% Value of \ifnum's first TeX-<number>-quantity and relation-sign "=" gathered/obtained. 
% Digit-character-token "0" of `\ifnum`'s second  TeX-<number>-quantity found, thus the process of
% gathering  tokens that belong to \ifnum's second TeX-<number>-quantity is still in progress and now
% forms a process of gathering more digit-character-tokens or something that terminates the
% process of gathering, hereby expanding expandable tokens:
\spacebottom⟨space-token⟩\expandafter\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname\relax\fi
```

What happens now depends on the definition/meaning of `\spacebottom`.

Assuming `\spacebottom` denotes a length-register/a length, `\spacebottom` is neither a digit-character-token nor an expandable token and therefore triggers termination of the process of gathering more digit-character-tokens that belong to `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. Unlike a space-token `\spacebottom` will not be discarded:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% Value of \ifnum's first TeX-<number>-quantity and relation-sign "=" gathered/obtained.
% Digit-character-token "0" gathered as the only element of the sequence of tokens that
% forms \ifnum's second TeX-<number>-quantity. Value of \ifnum's second
% TeX-<number>-quantity obtained as "0" thereof.
% Evaluation of truth-value of statement takes place:
\spacebottom⟨space-token⟩\expandafter\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname\relax\fi
```

In case the value gathered from `\thetype@box` does not equal the value `0`, the statement is false and everything until/including the matching `\else` or, in case a matching `\else` is not present, the matching `\fi` will be discarded without expansion. Tokens behind a matching `\else` would be processed.

In case the value gathered from `\thetype@box` does equal the value `0`, the statement is true, therefore tokens will be processed/expanded until encountering the matching `\else` or, in case a matching `\else` is not present, the matching `\fi`:

In this case the control-word-token `\spacebottom` will be processed. Assuming the control-word-token `\spacebottom` denotes a length-register/a length, LaTeX silently discards the *⟨space-token⟩* and starts gathering tokens for a local assignment to that length-register, hereby expanding expandable tokens. (Be aware that `\setlength` does a **local** assignment/an assignment restricted to the current scope to a length-register while an assignment in terms of `\setcounter` denotes a **global** assignment to the `\count`-register that underlies the LaTeX-counter in question.)

Hereby expansion of `\expandafter` is triggered. Expansion of `\expandafter` in turn triggers expansion of the next but one token if that is expandable. When expansion of the next but one token is done, then expansion of `\expandafter` is done. The next token outgoing from `\expandafter` is `\csname`. The next but one token outgoing from `\expandafter` is the token `s`. So `\expandafter` triggers expansion of the token `s`. In case `s` is a non-active/non-expandable character-token, this will have no effect. Then expansion of `\expandafter` is done and a stage is reached which is similar to:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% \ifnum-condition evaluated to be "true".
% Expanding/gathering tokens for the assignment to the length-register `\spacebottom` in progress:
\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname\relax\fi
```

Now expansion of `\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname` takes place and (depending on what is provided as argument `#1`) probably yields a control-word-token. Assume `foo` was provided as `#1`. Under that presumption the control-word-token `\spacebottomfoo` is delivered and a stage is reached which is similar to:

```
% \ifnum's matching \fi is not yet encountered.
% \ifnum-condition evaluated to be "true".
% Expanding/gathering tokens for the assignment to the length-register `\spacebottom` in progress:
\spacebottomfoo\relax\fi
```

Now `\spacebottomfoo` gets fully evaluated and hereby fully expanded if expandable. `\relax` is a non-expandable no-op which triggers terminating the process of gathering tokens for the  assignment to the length-register `\spacebottom` in case terminating that process is not triggered otherwise.

When the process of gathering tokens for the assignment is terminated, the assignment takes place, i.e., `\spacebottom` gets assigned the length-value which came from fully evaluating `\spacebottomfoo`.

Then `\relax` is encountered which is a no-op.

Then `\fi`, which finishes/matches the `\ifnum`, is encountered and discarded.

---

Removing obsolete `\expandafter` and adding a space for ensuring proper termination of the process of gathering digit-character-tokens for `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity you can probably do as follows:

```
\makeatletter
...
% Inside definition-text where #1 is available:
...
\ifnum\thetype@box=0 %<-The space must be as it terminates gathering 
                     %  digits after 0. It gets discarded by \ifnum.
  \setlength{\spacebottom}{\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname}%
\fi
...
% Outside definition-text:
...
\makeatother
```

Addendum—for the sake of completeness of this answer:

As already noted in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535990/118714):

In case `\thetype@box` comes from `\newcounter{type@box}`, it is not ensured that `\thetype@box` will always deliver a representation of the LaTeX-counter `type@box` in terms of digit-character-tokens that form a decimal number consisting of Arabic digits.

With `\newcounter{⟨counter⟩}` the macro `\the⟨counter⟩` serves the purpose of delivering a representation of the value of the counter in question in the way in which the user wants that value to be represented in the text of her/his document.
E.g., `\the⟨counter⟩` could be defined to deliver a representation in terms of roman numerals.
E.g., `\the⟨counter⟩` could be defined to deliver a representation in terms of letters of the alphabet.
E.g., `\the⟨counter⟩` could be defined to deliver a representation in hexadecimal/duodecimal/octal/(balanced) ternary/binary number system or whatever.

`\value{⟨counter⟩}` will deliver the value of the corresponding LaTeX-counter in terms of a set of digit-character-tokens of category code 12(other) that form a representation of the value as decimal number consisting of Arabic digits.

Thus— as already pointed out by egreg—in case `\thetype@box` comes from `\newcounter{type@box}`, you might be better off using `\value{..}` instead of `\the..`:

```
\makeatletter
...
% Inside definition-text where #1 is available:
...
\ifnum\value{type@box}=0 %<-The space must be as it terminates gathering 
                         %  digit-character-tokens after 0. It gets 
                         %  discarded by \ifnum.
  \setlength{\spacebottom}{\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname}%
\fi
...
% Outside definition-text:
...
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

It is badly written code.

First of all, `\expandafter` does nothing useful and can (should, actually) be omitted.

The idea is to look at the current meaning or value of `\thetype@box` (we cannot know if it is a macro or a numeric register). If it is 0, then the code will do something and nothing otherwise.

If `\thetype@box` comes from something like `\newcounter{type@box}`, then it could be better not relying to `\thetype@box`, which is the representation of the counter's value, not the value.

Second: good TeX programming leaves a space after a constant (0, in this case). In the present code this is not really of a concern, but in other instances the missing space can cause untimely expansion. Alternatively, since the code appears in a `\makeatletter` context (because of `\thetype@box`), one can use `\z@`.

Better coding would be

```latex
\ifnum\value{type@box}=0
  \setlength{\spacebottom}{\csname spacebottom#1\endcsname}%
\fi
```

(keep `\thetype@box` if `type@box` is not a LaTeX counter). The endline after `0` is equivalent to a space.

Now `\spacebottom` should be a length register (defined with `\newlength` or `\newdimen`).

What does the code do? If the value stored in the counter `type@box` (or in the macro `\thetype@box`) is 0, the conditional evaluates to “true”, so the code up to the matching `\else` or `\fi` is executed. There is no `\else`, so TeX will use whatever happens to come along until `\fi`.

The length register is set to the length corresponding to `\spacebottombar`, assuming that the code is part of a macro definition of a macro `\foo` with one or more arguments and is called like

```
\foo{bar}
```

The macro `\spacebottombar` should have been defined in advance, or you'd get an error upon executing the `\setlength` command.

This is because `\csname<characters>\endcsname` is equivalent to the command whose name is a backslash followed by `<characters>` and `\setlength{<register>}{<material>}` performs complete expansion of `<material>` in order to find a suitable length to set the `<register>` to.